# Create a function that identifiies object type and passes form depending on what type the object is

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, function

I have a model named product, and depending on the type of product I would like to pass a form. So, for example, if the product type is "Clothing", then render a form to select a size (S, M, L, etc...)

I've tried creating a view that passes the product to a template, and then made a function within the view called is_clothing that says product type is clothing.

```py
# models.py

PRODUCT_TYPE = [
    ('C', 'Clothing'),
    ('A', 'Accessory'),
    ('F', 'Furniture'),
]

class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    type = models.Charfield(blank=True, choices=PRODUCT_TYPE)

# views.py

def product_view(request, slug):
    productvariant = get_object_or_404(ProductVariants, slug=slug)
    form = ProductSizeForm
    # Function that defines whether product type is clothing
    def is_clothing():
        product.type == "Clothing"


    context = {
        'product' : productvariant,
        'form' : form
    }
    return render(request, "products/product-page.html", context)
```

```html
<!--TEMPLATE-->
{% if product.is_clothing %}
    {{ form }}
{% endif %}
```

As I said I was hoping to render the sizes form if the product type is clothing, but I'm not getting any results. Any ideas?

Comment: `form` should be an *instance* of `ProductSizeForm` not the class itself. Also why do you think `productvariant.is_clothing` is defined (which is what you're doing by calling `if product.is_clothing`) if you defined it on the view? just check it in your template directly `{% if product.type == "Clothing" %}`.

Comment: Thanks! Finally got it working.